# Crear varios botones o switches con ListView en android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

hola mi pregunta es como crear botones o switches en android studio, he visto ejemplos pero solo con texto y eso me queda claro, lo que necestio es poner botones o switches con ListView y que se vayan agregando en lista gracias!!

codigo java

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

    final String[] datos = new String[];
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Switch mySwitch = new Switch(this);
    mySwitch.setText("Press me");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, datos);
    ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

  }
}
```

y este es el xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10px"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: llenas el listView con una clase?

Comment: si, quisiera hacerlo en una sola clase pero no se si se pueda, ya lo hice con  listview pero mostrando puro texto en la clase main

Comment: sólo crea objetos tipo Button en la clase

Comment: La pregunta que te sugerí no fue de ayuda? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90441/como-programar-botones-o-switches-en-lista-programaticamente-en-android

Comment: Porque no agregas el código de lo que has intentado. Si realizas este tipo de preguntas sin ser especifico, obtendras el mismo tipo de respuestas, y podría ser cerrada. Recuerda que SOes no es un foro.

Comment: les pido una disculpa creo que no me di a entender este es el codigo que estoy haciendo, me pidieron que lo agregara ovbiamente esta mal

Comment: Ya agregue mi codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es personalizar los items de tu *ListView* a tu gusto (ahí añades cualquier *widget* que necesites), crear un *Adapter* y asignarlo a tu *ListView*.

Busca en internet **personalizar item de *ListView*** y te saldran un montón de tutoriales, en lo personal te recomiendo los de [Hermosa Programación](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/), son muy completos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: En ese enlace no encontre nada de lo que menciona la pregunta